# Dotted type at pattern matching fails

Tags: scala, code-generation, pattern-matching

I have seen that these situations work fine (Notice the *scala.Int* instead of *Int*):

```
def f(l: List[scala.Int]): List[scala.Int] = l
val l: List[scala.Int] = List[scala.Int]()
```

But using the whole path fails in the following example:

```
def f[T: TypeTag](l: List[T]): Int = {
  l match {
    case li: List[scala.Int] if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[scala.Int] => li(0)
    case _ => 0
  }
}
```

Is it possible to escape this situation while keeping the *scala.Int*? The thing is that I need to autogenerate this code, and I would like to avoid using *import redefinitions*.

Comment: This code wouldn't work anyway, because you can't match on generics, because of the type erasure. The program does not have information about the type of a `List` at runtime.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right (that could be solved with TypeTags). But think in the following function: `def f[C[_]](l: C[Int]): Int = l match {
    case l: List[_] => l(0)
  }` If I do so, it doesn't compile. It needs *List[Int]* instead of *List[_]*. An *asInstanceOf* in the RHS is quite ugly.

Comment: Sure it does not compile, because it's not correct. But matching on a generic is even worse, because it does not crash at compile-, but at runtime.

Comment: We are leaving the topic... I just wanted to keep a simple example. Anyway, I have updated it with the real code. Is it possible to keep the _li: List[scala.Int]_ notation (since _li: List[Int]_ compiles)?